# jQuery change input value on div mouseover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change an input value using jQuery mouse over.

Scenario: I got 5 div having different colors and user names. When mouseover a div the input text change (and for color input the background color) data according to database values, when change div the text displays new data.

using PHP I echo the part of the script to handle the mouseover function

```
<?php 
    $myId = '1';
    $uname = 'user1';
    $ucolor = 'FFFFFF';
    echo "<script>
            $('$myId').mouseover( function () {
                $('#uname').val('" . $uname . "'),
                $('#ucolor').val('" . $ucolor ."'),
                $('#ucolor').css('background-color', '" . $ucolor . "')
            })
        </script>";
```

This work if i change mouseover() to hover(), but display only the first element, if i do a mouse over the second element data doesn't change.

Comment: You are missing a # in your jquery for the id

Comment: `$(' . $myId . ').mo...`

Comment: adding $(' # " . $myID . "').mo... seems working, but only for the first element again

Comment: an ID is distinct in html so use `.` for class: `$(.' . $myId . ').mouseover([...])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Put your script after body tag:

```
<body>
<div class="hh" id="1"></div>
<input type="text" id="uname" />
<input type="text" id="ucolor" />

<div class="hh" id="2"></div>
</body>
<?php 
    $myId = '1';
    $uname = 'user1';
    $ucolor = 'FFFFFF';
    echo "<script>
            $('#$myId').mouseover( function () {  // add # here
                $('#uname').val('" . $uname . "'),
                $('#ucolor').val('" . $ucolor ."'),
                $('#ucolor').css('background-color', '" . $ucolor . "')
            })
        </script>";

$myId = '2';
$uname = 'user2';
$ucolor = 'FFF555';
echo "<script>
        $('#$myId').mouseover( function () { console.log('fdgfdg')
            $('#uname').val('" . $uname . "'),
            $('#ucolor').val('" . $ucolor ."'),
            $('#ucolor').css('background-color', '" . $ucolor . "')
        })
    </script>";


?>
```

Comment: The script is already after the body tag, sorry for not specified, this is a cutted part of code

Comment: add # in mouseover event

Comment: i can't understand, adding # after (function() { # will cause Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: no in $('#$myId').mouseover( function () {     // telling to add # before $myId

Comment: it's ok i'm doing this                 $('#" .$myId . "').mouseover( function () {

Comment: no...please see my code..I have already added in my posted answer...add like that

Comment: I've updated copy and paste your sample, but nothing changed, I got only the first element in input, when i mouseover other elements nothing change

Comment: Yes, code is executed by a php while, so is exaclty the same

Comment: The ids should be different/unique for all input boxes...is it so??

Comment: Yes, the $myId changed using a $myId++ so every time the code execute will increase the ID number

Comment: I have posted code for 2 divs above..check that..you can see ids for div and input boxes are different... it should be like that

Comment: I see but the input name don't change every time, must to update the data in one input

Comment: reading console i see all the lines fdgfdg
index.2.php:85 fdgfdg
index.2.php:109 fdgfdg
index.2.php:133 fdgfdg
index.2.php:157 fdgfdg

Comment: Wait, i've found an error in my SQL query, now it's working as expected! Thanks a lot and excuse me if i don't see the error first! Will mark the question as answered!

Answer (score 0):

In general the div or any DOM must have a unique ID value. Try using class selector(.) instead of ID selector(#).

Comment: using class selector don't change the result, i got only the first element and don't change on mouseover

Comment: Try to place the code inside the $(document).ready(function(){ /* your code */ });